# Creating Workspace for Satellite Imagery in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, mosaic, satellite, sentinel-2, image-mosaic

I am trying create mosaic from Sentinel – 2 satellite data. To realize this task I’ve used “New Ortho Mapping Workspace” and “Satellite” Type. In next step I’ve chosen appropriate sensor type, the same Spatial Reference like images, and I’ve indicated the path to the folder witch Sentinel – 2 images. (Folder Name: S2A_MSIL2A_20181014T093031_N0209_R136_T34UFV_20181014T111722.SAFE).

The other options have been default.

After pressing the finish button the message appears:

> Queued...
>
> - Running...
> - Building image collection...
> - Start Time: środa, 13 marca 2019 09:25:40
> - 2019-03-13T09:25:43.774: Loading raster datasets
> - 2019-03-13T09:25:45.013: Completed crawling 14 data source items.
>     Added 0 mosaic dataset items.
> - 2019-03-13T09:25:45.022: Error: 8004205f: No new mosaic dataset item
>     was added.
> - Succeeded at Wednesday, 13 March 2019 09:25:45 (Elapsed Time: 5,40
>     seconds)
>
> ---

What kind of data should be imported to receive a mosaic?

Blended RGB images in .tif format or raw data downloaded form the “https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/” website?